# "echo" html content to file in perl

Tags: perl

I often use "echo $xxx >file" in perl, normally for debug. It is ugly but simple, it fit "There's More Than One Way To Do It".

But now I have a problem with `@_`. `@_` contains a web page.

```
`echo "@_" >/tmp/curl`;
`echo """@_""" >/tmp/curl`;

sh: -c: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
sh: -c: line 5: ` <meta description="

`echo "'"@_"'" >/tmp/curl`;
`echo '"'@_'"' >/tmp/curl`;

sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: -c: line 0: `echo "'"<html>'
```

I want to know if this can be done or not.

ps: I had tested bash, it works in terminal.

```
r='<meta description="Ch<br><br>This'; echo $r >/tmp/curl
```

But perl can not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$r='<meta description="Ch<br><br>This';
`echo "$r" >/tmp/curl`; exit;
```

I think here has some trick can do it.

Comment: Pls do not mark it duplicate. My require is different.

Comment: instead of echo, use print and for quote the string.. use qw http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/qw_function.html

Comment: I think qw can not deal with a whole html text.

Answer (score 5):

Oh dear, no. What you're doing with the backticks is spawning a shell just to print something to a file. As you notice, special characters cause problems, *and allow injecting commands*. In theory, you could escape everything the shell considers special, but that's annoying to do.

Just use the proper file handling functions and make a function to contain all the steps:

```
sub dumptofile($@) {
    my $file = shift;
    if (open F, ">", $file) {
        print F @_;
        close F; 
    } else {
        warn "Can't open $file: $!"
    }
}

dumptofile("/tmp/curl", "some output\n");
```

Now, if you don't want to type all that, you could condense it to something uglier, ignoring error checking and all (as in my first version). Or save the full version in a module and put it somewhere in your Perl's include path ([see `perl -I`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)).

```
# Dumptofile.pm
package Dumptofile;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw/import/;
our @EXPORT = qw/dumptofile/;

sub dumptofile($@) {
    my $file = shift;
    if (open my $fh, ">", $file) {
        print $fh @_;
        close $fh; 
    } else {
        warn "Can't open $file: $!"
    }
}
1;
```

use:

```
perl -MDumptofile -e 'dumptofile("out.txt", "blahblah");
```

Comment: `open ... or return;`, if the file can't be opened for writing.

Comment: I really would have wanted something dirty, unreadable, and short, to better match the compactness of the backtick-echo. Though even what I originally wrote could have been compacted more. Perhaps there is an existing module to do this in one function call, but I didn't find one.

Comment: I just hate use "open", it need at least 3 lines. But I think you are right, all strange characters are imported, seems bash can not **hold** this. I just hope someone has trick on this.

Comment: In the `package` Dumptofile.pm `use Fatal qw/open/` module so that it quits upon error AND instead of global `filehandle` `F` , use a lexical filehandle, so that it autocloses when it goes out of scope

Comment: @RakeshSharma, yes, point on the filehandle, though better to `close` explicitly anyway. I'll leave fine-tuning of the behaviour for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Sorry I like dirty perl....

```
`echo \'@_\' >/tmp/curl`;
```

Thanks for reminding me, Rakesh Sharma. I change code to this.

```
push @_, 'that "is"you\'ok.'; 
for(@_){s/'/"/g;}; `echo \'@_\' >/tmp/curl`;
```

Comment: Just ensure that any single quotes in `@_` are properly escaped.

Comment: Yes, I will pay attention to this.

Comment: Now you have much more heavy lifting to do I'm afraid. All your $ backquotes need to double quoted to preserve them, Better to single quote stuff.

Comment: I change to double quotes only because it just more like bash. yes, the $ would trouble me again. I change back to single quotes. thanks.